# Scan columns for a value and use the result to select other columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have one bigquery table with 30 columns:

```
strcol,strcol1,strcol2,..  startstr, startstr1, startstr2,..   endstr, endstr1, endstr2,..
1111, 2343, 1012......     "car", "boat", "scooter".....       "plane", "bike", "boat"
9999, 1012, 3333......     "scooter", "boat", "scooter".....       "boat", "bike", "boat"
```

I need to scan all columns "strcol" to find a number. If I find the number I need to use the correspondent "startstr" and "endstr".

Example:
Number 1012 is present in column "strcol2" then I need to use "startstr2" and "endstr2". My select statement only needs two columns. Result would be something like:

```
start, end
scooter, boat
boat, bike
```

I was thinking of creating an array of strcol...strcol9 and try to find the number and return the index, then use this index to find the correct startstr and endstr. But I don't know how to do this. Maybe there are much better alternatives? Any ideas?

The number 1012 will always be fixed and will never change.

Cheers,
Cris

Comment: provide sample of input data and sample of expected result. no need in all 30 columns - just few will be ok for us to understand what exactly you need

Comment: ok added some more info. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and might look less "advanced/verbose", so might be easy for you to handle/maintain

```
#standardSQL
select 
  regexp_extract(line, r'"startstr' || pattern) start,
  regexp_extract(line, r'"endstr' || pattern) `end`,
from `project.dataset.table` t, 
  unnest([to_json_string(t)]) line,
  unnest(generate_array(0, array_length(split(line))/3 - 1)) index,
  unnest([if(index > 0, cast(index as string), '') || '":"?([^,"]+)"?']) pattern
where regexp_extract(line, r'"strcol' || pattern) = cast(1012 as string)
```

When applied to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This actually got me in the right direction and with some few adjustments to my data I got it to work. Thanks Mikhail!

Comment: great. glad it worked for you :o) i know this one is much easier to manage and adjust to more specific needs - easier than with my first answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (
  CASE
    WHEN strcol = 1012 THEN STRUCT(startstr, endstr)
    WHEN strcol1 = 1012 THEN STRUCT(startstr1, endstr1)
    WHEN strcol2 = 1012 THEN STRUCT(startstr2, endstr2)
  END
).*
FROM dataset.table
WHERE 1012 IN (strcol, strcol1, strcol2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need to know the suffix of strcol to know what suffix to use in startstr and endstr.

Comment: `CASE` maybe then?

Comment: Yes that's a good alternative...But...In my example I have 10 strcol but in reality I have 34 :( so I wanted to do something else...but you're right this would be my plan-b. Thanks Sergey. If nobody have another solution I will mark this as an answer.

Comment: @Cristian . . . That is not in your desired results.  This answers the question that you have asked.  I would suggest you ask a *new* question if what you want is actually different.

Comment: ok I will ask a new question. Marked this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select start, `end`
from (
  select 
    max(if(key='strcol', value, null)) as strcol,
    cast(max(if(key='strcol', value, null)) as int64) as value,
    max(if(key='startstr', value, null)) as start,
    max(if(key='endstr', value, null)) as `end`
  from (
    select format('%t', t) id, 
      regexp_extract(col, r'^[^\d]+') key,
      regexp_extract(col, r'[\d]*$') offset,
      value
    from `project.dataset.table` t,
    unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) as kv,
    unnest([struct(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] as col, split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] as value)])
  )
  group by id, offset
)
where value = 1012
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Sorry Mikhail, its super advanced :D lol I was on my phone and my smiley did not make it...

Comment: @Cristian - if above answer looks too advanced to you - check out another option I just posted as new answer. it might still look advanced - but less verbose and easy to swallow I think. but in general - your question is such that simple answer will just not fly! :o)